# JList does not show selected value

Tags: java, swing, selection, jlist

Here is my question:
In a small Swing app, I create a `JList`, which works with a `ListDefaultModel`.
I put some values in it, and when I try to click on these values, nothing graphical changes.

I mean: the selection event is raised, but I do not have the small rectangle, which is usually colored blue.

I hope you'll have some ideas.

Comment: Perhaps the selection color is white? Try `list.setSelectionBackground()`

Comment: are you ablr to post here sort runnable code that demonstrated you problem with that, http://sscce.org/

Comment: *"Here is my question:"*  Side note.  You have described a problem with a GUI, but you did not ask a question.  For the help of people who do not speak English well, and for those of us reading questions after a 22 hour programming spree, you might add one.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, such errors are often caused by other exceptions thrown in your code. In other words, if a NullPointerException in your code was be thrown as a result of SWING trying to retrieve a value to be displayed in your list, then your GUI might become unresponsive or behave weird.

My first advise would then be to try out a very simple example like:

```
DefaultListModel m = new DefaultListModel();
m.addElement("One");
m.addElement("Two");
m.addElement("Three");
m.addElement("Four");
m.addElement("Five");
SomeList.setModel(m);
```

If that works, then check your code to see if something might be wrong. If the above example does not work either, then i'd say you should post some more details here.

Good luck!

Comment: It was a mistake of mine, about the cell renderer. Thanks for all your answers :).

Comment: @deathiop You could post your solution as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (thanks to the OP for the hint). Turned out that my `ListCellRenderer` class was implementing the `ListCellRenderer` interface instead of extending `DefaultListCellRenderer`. And call`super.getListCellRendererComponent`.

So use

```
class MyListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {}
```

instead of

```
class MyListCellRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {}
```